# aggregate columns not found in order by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I trying to sort based on two aggregate columns

```
SELECT  count(ids) as no_of_ids , sum((rate > 0)::int)as right_count
From  profile_performance
group By  p.profile_id
Order by  (right_count/predictions) desc limit 10
```

error I get is :

```
ERROR:  column "right_count" does not exist
LINE 6: Order by  (right_count/no_of_ids::float) desc limit 10
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "right_count" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 413
```

But the following works fine:

```
SELECT  count(ids) as no_of_ids , sum((rate > 0)::int)as right_count
From  profile_performance
group By  p.profile_id
Order by  right_count,predictions desc limit 10
```

Is it possible to fix it without using a outer query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT  count(ids) as no_of_ids , sum((rate > 0)::int) as right_count
From  profile_performance
group By  p.profile_id
Order by  (sum((rate > 0)::int) / predictions) desc
limit 10 ;
```

Apparently, Postgres allows you to refer to a column alias in the `order by`.  However, it does not recognize expressions containing them.

This is even clearly [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-order.html):

> Note that an output column name has to stand alone, that is, it cannot
>   be used in an expression — for example, this is not correct:
>
> ```
> SELECT a + b AS sum, c FROM table1 ORDER BY sum + c;          -- wrong
> ```
>
> This restriction is made to reduce ambiguity. There is still ambiguity
>   if an ORDER BY item is a simple name that could match either an output
>   column name or a column from the table expression. The output column
>   is used in such cases. This would only cause confusion if you use AS
>   to rename an output column to match some other table column's name.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I have simplified the query here, its complex and running on a big dataset. Does the repetition cause the expression to be executed twice ?

Comment: @snaikar . . . For Postgres, I don't know.  However, the execution of the `sum()` is not particularly expensive (the expensive part is the `group by`).  If that is really a concern, you can use a subquery.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the pointing to me to the documentation . I will see the explain to see if it is repeating